# Kernel panic when passing noatime in bootargs

Tags: linux, filesystems, linux-kernel

I have an embedded system using jffs2 and want to pass `rootflags=noatime` in the kernel `bootargs` parameter.

This results in a kernel panic:

```
jffs2: Error: unrecognized mount option 'noatime' or missing value
[...]
No filesystem could mount root, tried:  jffs2
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(31,3)
```

However, if I boot normally and then remount the jffs2 filesystem with noatime, it works fine:

```
$ mount -o remount,noatime /
```

I am puzzled by this as according to [the documentation](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/BootPrompt-HOWTO-3.html), the rootflags argument "allows you to give options pertaining to the mounting of the root filesystem just as you would to the mount program".

Looks like a kernel bug to me, but on the other hand it seems so obvious that perhaps I am overlooking something.

I have tested this with kernel versions 3.7 and 3.14.

Can someone shed some light?

Comment: why you don't you the fstab for setting noatime in your /?

Comment: I can do that of course but that does not answer my question (why rootflags=noatime doesn't work)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Googling `rootflags noatime` brings up this post from 2003 by Andrew Morton, perhaps it still applies.

http://lkml.org/lkml/2003/8/12/236

> > While testing something, I tried to boot with 'rootflags=noatime', and
> >     found the system wouldn't boot, as ext3, ext2, and reiserfs all failed to
> >     recognize the option.  Looking at the code in fs/ext3/super.c:parse_options()
> >     and init/do_mounts.c:root_data_setup(), it appears to be impossible
> >     to set any of the filesystem-independent flags via rootflags, which explains
> >     the special-case code for the 'ro' and 'rw' flags.  However, there doesn't
> >     seem to be any way to pass nodev, noatime, nodiratime, or any of the other
> >     flags.  (And yes, all 3 of those make sense in my environment - it's a laptop
> >     and I don't need atime, and I use devfs so nodev on the root makes sense too).
>
> The fs-independent options are parsed in user space by mount(8), and
>   are passed into the kernel as individual bits in a `flags' argument.

Comment: Would this be a documentation bug then ?

Comment: I see the documentation you linked is also dated 2003.  So you could make that argument.  If this was a common problem I'd blame the kernel for being inconsistent instead.  In practice... if you keep reading the thread it suggests that using an initrd/initramfs to mount the rootfs instead could work around it, and initramfs is the common case nowadays (at least for non-embedded).  My search also brought up specific complaints that this problem happened when booting without an initramfs.  Which I should have mentioned if I wasn't being lazy. Eg https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=61601

Comment: This still seems to be an issue, just ran into this with a 5.4 kernel (only works with an initramfs).